# Is there arabic latex allow me to write mathematical paper with question arabic and latine math?

Tags: math-mode, arabic, right-to-left

I would like to write a book in mathematics but with questions in Arabic and 
Latin mathmetical symbols (for example, between two Arabic words there might be a Latin mathematical symbol).

**Note**: For example pleas check [this pdf](http://sefroumaths.voila.net/1.sm/autres.profs/abdellah.benelkhatir/04.fonctios.gener.pdf) to see what I want. Here's an image of the first page:

[image]

Thank you for any help !!

Comment: I up-loaded an image of the first page of the linked PDF so everyone can quickly see what you want to achieve. I hope it's OK.

Comment: what is your question exactly. It seems that you need to learn xelatex.

Answer (score 1):

MWE using `pdflatex` (i.e., `xelatex` not required) with `selectlanguage` from the `babel` package:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[LAE,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[arabic,english]{babel}

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{arabic}
النظر في الصيغة التالية:
\selectlanguage{english}
\begin{equation}
f(x)=x^2+\frac{1}{x^3}
\end{equation}
\selectlanguage{arabic}
المتغير
\selectlanguage{english}$x$\selectlanguage{arabic}والتربيعية
\end{document}
```

Result:
[image: mixed arabic and latin]
Note that you need a text editor that supports right-to-left script (the StackExchange website seems left-to-right oriented...) and utf8 encoding. If you use Ubuntu (etc.) you can install the `texlive-lang-arabic` package with `apt`. See also http://www.ctan.org/pkg/arabi.