# Writing book in Arabic -- Only the Equations in English/Latin

Tags: languages, books, arabic

### Question

I want to write a **book in Arabic** (I have an Arabic keyboard, so I don't need a converter). By Arabic book I mean literally Arabic:

- title,
- table of contents
- etc

all in Arabic.

The **equations**, however, I want to write them in **English/Latin**.

### Related

http://ctan.triasinformatica.nl/language/arabic/arabi/arabi/texmf/doc/latex/arabi/user_guide.pdf

This link helped a lot but it was for Arabic texts in an English main document.

[Is there arabic latex allow me to write mathematical paper with question arabic and latine math?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/273050/is-there-arabic-latex-allow-me-to-write-mathematical-paper-with-question-arabic)

I already checked these two (and plenty other sites).

Comment: MiKTeX is good. I don't think that there are significant differences between the LaTeX distributions. In addition, I edited your question.

Comment: What do you mean with English equations? Do you mean Latin alphabet like `\sin` and `\cos` together with Arabic numerals :)? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_numerals

Comment: thanks for editing my question !
by english equations i meant latin indeed. so basically an arbic book with arabic explanation but eqaution are writtin in latin (left to right)

Comment: Ok. You can edit your question yourself in the future. Going to bed now. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly do this using XeTeX and polyglossia. In the preamble of your document, you should do the following:

```
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{*Your Font Here*}
```

That sets you up to have the document in Arabic. On my version of TeXLive, it automatically switches equations to LTR english. So just type your equations as normal (example with hebrew)

```
ואז אנחנו רואים  
$e=mc^2$
```

becomes

[image: our output]

So all you need to do is type as normal.